# How to use CodeIgniter dompdf for large dataset

Tags: php, codeigniter, dompdf

I'm generating `PDF` file in `CodeIgniter` using `dompdf`.But it gives me a blank out with no errors. If I pass limit to my query then the `PDF` gets generated properly but as remove limit from query its gives me a blank output. Same thing happens when I used `mpdf`.
Can any one help me with a solution?

my code is as follows

```
function pdf_create_param($html, $filename, $stream=TRUE)  {
    require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");

    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
    $dompdf->load_html($html);
    $dompdf->set_paper("a3", "landscape" );
    $dompdf->render();

    if ($stream) {
      $dompdf->stream($filename.".pdf");
    } else {
      return $dompdf->output();
    }
}
```

Comment: PHP timeout / memory limit ?

Comment: are you trying to load remote content (images, css, js etc..)? also as karoly suggested maybe a timeout or memory limit error. I would suggest making sure error reporting is turned on by putting `error_reporting(E_ALL);` above the PDF generation code.

Comment: Yeh it showing me memory limit

Comment: So can u tell me what should i do to resolve it??

Comment: Can you increase your available memory. If not, one method I've found that helps with memory overloads is to break the PDF up into portions you could render each separately then combine them later. Beyond that it would help to see a sample of the HTML.

Comment: I have change memory limit.But now its showing this error  Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded in C:\wamp\www\admin\application\helpers\dompdf\include\frame_decorator.cls.php on line 308

Comment: Now do i have to increase execution time.....

Comment: That would seem to be the case. One other thought, are you using tables, if so do you have any table cells that are larger than a single page?